# animate flex-basis but keep initial height/width of child

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I want to animate the width of a flex-container but keep the inital width and hight of the child-container. Since my child-div gives the total height of my flex-items the container which carries the bg-image should stay at the same initial height.

```js
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.slideMe').toggleClass('visible');
  $('.btn').toggleClass('close');
});
```

```css
.flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
  }

  .slideMe {
  background:white;
  flex:0 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

  .slideMe.visible {
  flex: 0 30%;
  }

  .bg-image {
  flex: 1;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/547114/pexels-photo-547114.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  }

  .btn {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background: #000;
  color:#FFF;
  cursor:pointer
  }

  .btn.close {
  left:30%
  }

  .animate {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexWrapper">
   <div class="btn animate close">click</div>
   <div class="slideMe animate visible">
    <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="bg-image"></div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/psu2fhut/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to keep the aspect ratio, see JS/CSS notes. Hope this points you in the right direction.

```js
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.slideMe').toggleClass('visible');
    $('.btn').toggleClass('close');
    $('.slideBackground').toggleClass('active'); // This to set negative margin when user clicked button
});
```

```css
.flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
}

.slideMe { 
  background:white;
  flex: 0 0 30%; /* No grow, no shrink, while staying 30% of it's parent */
  overflow:hidden;
}

.whatever {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* May grow, may shrink */
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/547114/pexels-photo-547114.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slideBackground.active {
  margin-left: -30%; /* Set negative value based on text width */
}

.btn {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background: #000;
  color:#FFF;
  cursor:pointer
}

.btn.close {
  left:30%
}

.animate {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexWrapper">
<div class="btn animate close">click</div>
  <div class="slideMe animate visible">
   <div class="lorem">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="whatever animate slideBackground">
       <!-- slideBackground class added... cause this will be the actual element that's sliding. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice. Thanks a lot! :)